# Why app process ends when granted permission removed from app settings?

Tags: android, operating-system

**Device:** Samsung Galaxy A12

**Android Version:** 12

I encountered a strange behavior. I said strange because this my first experience about that. Maybe i am missing something. Please all you guys share your experiences, thoughts or suggestions.

This is what i have just come across:

1. Give storage permission (read/write) in app.
2. Push device home button and app goes background.
3. Go to app settings and remove the granted permission.
4. Logcat says that PROCESS ENDED
5. Go back to the app from recent apps.
6. A short splash appears and then the last page appears.
7. Guess what, everything recreates, viewModel variables set to default.. etc..

Before, when i tested apps with this scenario the app process never ended. Now, is this an official core Android OS choice or a device-specific behavior?

Comment: While docs say how to implement granting permissions and how to flow your logic through that, imagine how unmaintainable it would be to handle a (niche) case of user pausing the app and revoking permissions at any given moment. So as a solution process is killed and app is given the opportunity to undergo its regular permission check once again. And as far as I recall it was always the case, not sure what you describe as "before".

Comment: Isn't it possible to check the permission again without killing process? (for example in onResume)

Comment: there's no option to toggle it. And aside from mess that it would cause, there are also components (like services) that can be started with granted permissions and they aren't bound by activity lifecycles.

Answer (score 3):

> is this an official core Android OS choice

Yes.

> Before, when i tested apps with this scenario the app process never ended"

I do not know how you tested before, but the behavior you described has existed since the introduction of runtime permissions with Android 6.0, approximately 8 years ago.

Comment: Official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#app_process_terminates_when_permission_revoked